# Are the product and ratio of two characteristic functions still characteristic functions?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\bf X $ and $\bf Y$ be random vectors (that may be dependent). Let $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)=E[e^{i\sum X_it_i}]$ be the characteristic function of the random vector $\bf X$.

(1) Is $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ a characteristic function?

(2) Is $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)/ \varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ a characteristic function?

(3) What conditions are needed for $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ to be characteristic function?

(4) If $\bf Y$ is jointly normal then is $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ a characteristic function?

(5) If $\bf Y$ is uniform then is $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ a characteristic function?

(6) What are some commonly used distributions on $\bf Y$ that would make $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ a characteristic function?

I suspect the answers are (1) no (2) no (3) $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$ independent is one condition but there might be others (4)  yes (5) don't know (6) yes.

I'm trying to understand if $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ will be a characteristic function in ''most cases'' and if one would have to work hard to find a counterexample where $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)$ and $\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ are characteristic functions but $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ is characteristic function no matter which distributions $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$ have. Take vectors $\tilde {\bf X}$ and $\tilde {\bf Y}$ such that $\tilde {\bf X} \,{\buildrel d \over =}\, \bf X$, $\tilde {\bf Y} \,{\buildrel d \over =}\, \bf Y$ and the pair $(\tilde {\bf X},\tilde{ \bf Y})$ is independent. Then $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ is the characteristic function of the sum  $\tilde {\bf X}+\tilde{ \bf Y}$.

(2) The answer is negative in general, since the absolute value of $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)/ \varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ can be bigger than $1$.

Comment: Thanks. Are there conditions that also make $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)/\varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ a characteristic function? I recall something for Lukacs 1970 on decomposable characteristic functions, which I thought was this.

Comment: Surely $\varphi_{\bf X}(\bf t)/ \varphi_{\bf Y}(\bf t)$ may be a characteristic function, for example if you consider infinitely divisible distributions. But I did not come across any general result about that.